# How to change a number's digits in a recursive function? C++

Tags: c++, function, recursion, numbers, digits

I have to input a number `n`, an `a` digit and a `b` digit and output the number `n` with all the `a` digits in it replaced by a `b` one. For example:

```
Input:
n = 1561525
a = 5
b = 9

Output:
n = 1961929
```

Should be recursive ! I didn't post any code as I've done it in a non-recursive way but apparently it's not even close to what I need.

Thanks for the help !

Comment: At least you can specify programming language

Comment: @u_mulder Oh.. I'm sorry... I did just now.

Comment: I don't understand why it should be recursive. In my opinion, this is not a problem that is particularly well suited for recursion.

Comment: @SebastianNegraszus - School assignment, that's why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this, it works but maybe it is to much C

```
int convert(int num, int a, int b)
{
    if( num )
    {
        int res = convert(num/10,a,b);
        int t = num%10;
        res *=10;
        t = t == a ? b:t;
        res = res + t;
        return res;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Divide by 10 the initial number, until nothing left of it, and then construct it again replacing a with b.

Comment: Thanks, it works! Two questions though. First, could you please elaborate on the t = t == a ? b:t; line as I don't really understand it? Second, this does not seem like a typical recursive function where it returns itself. Is it really one and could it be made more like one?

Comment: 1. this expression `t==a ? b:t;` called "ternary if" google it if you want to use it, or replace with regular if. 2. This is recursion, this function calls it self, simply after each recursive call some operations should be done on the result.

Answer (score 1):

To make things easier, you can convert the number into a string (a `char[]` in C++). Then, it's a simple matter of iterating over it and checking at each step if the number we want to replace was found in the current position. For a possible solution, here's an implementation of the algorithm in Python - one of the nice things of the language is that it reads almost as pseudocode, and it should be relatively simple to port to C++:

```
def aux(n, a, b, i):
    if i == len(n):
        return ''
    elif n[i] == a:
        return b + aux(n, a, b, i+1)
    else:
        return n[i] + aux(n, a, b, i+1)

def change(n, a, b):
    return int(aux(str(n), str(a), str(b), 0))
```

It works as expected:

```
change(1561525, 5, 9)
=> 1961929
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but could it be done in a single function? It's just that my assignment is tested on some kind of a software and I have no idea how strict it is.

Comment: @user3213110 we need extra parameters to do the looping using recursion. I don't think that using a helper function is a problem, as long as the main function adheres to the requirements of the testing software in terms of expected input, output, name and number of parameters

Comment: I have a problem converting the code to C++. I use char for declaring the variables in the first function but it keeps telling me I need pointers. Neither `len` or `strlen` work even though I've included the `<string>` library... I'm lost.

Comment: @user3213110 concentrate in the essential: the `aux` function receives a `string` or a `char[]`, it's up to you, what matters is that you need to access each element by index, that you need to know the size of it and that, when building the answer, you need to concatenate one char at a time. Pick a data representation that meets all the required operations, and off you go

Answer (score 1):

So the easiest and safest way I can think of, is by using `std::replace`:

```
int replace(int num, int d1, int d2) {
    string s = std::to_string(num);                     // convert to string
    std::replace( s.begin(), s.end(), d1+'0', d2+'0');  // call std::replace

    return atoi( s.c_str() );                           // return the int
}
```

---

Now if you **really** have to use recursion (there is no need for it here), here's one possible solution:

```
using std::string;

// recursive function, accepts a string, current index, c2 replaces c1
string replace_rec (string s, unsigned index, char c1, char c2) {

    // check if the it's still a valid index
    if (index < s.size()) {

        // if this is a char to be converted, do so
        if (s[index] == c1)
            s[index] = c2;

        // call itself but with an updated string and incremented index
        replace_rec(s, index+1, c1, c2);
    }

    // the last call will result in the string with all chars checked. return it
    return s;
}

// call this function with input, the num to be replaced and what with
int replace(int num, int d1, int d2) {

    string s = std::to_string(num);   // convert to string

    // convert the result back to int and return it.
    return atoi( replace_rec(s, 0, d1+'0', d2+'0').c_str() ); 
}
```

---

In any case, you can call your `replace()` function like this:

```
int main(){

    cout << replace (4578, 4, 9);   // output: 9578
    cin.get();
}
```